# How to create abstract class reference in groovy lambda expression

Tags: groovy, lambda

Probably it is a silly question I am asking, due to I am new to groovy.

I have below code which need to use groovy expression

Java Snippet:
          `.toArray(X509Certificate[]::new))` java.security.cert.X509Certificate is abstract class

I need this to use same in groovy. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you have before `.toArray(` ?

Comment: I am following below reference to create webclient object with own certs. https://github.com/Ivan-Vshtd/ssl-secure/blob/master/src/main/java/com/attempt/sslsecure/config/UserWebClientConfig.java#L82

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this in different way to create. if need anyone help,
               `toArray({new X509Certificate[size]}))`